# Azure, Windows 8.1, Docker: az commands does not work in docker toolbox

Tags: bash, azure, docker, azure-cli

I did:

- install Azure/azure cli 2.0
- update Path
- install Docker toolbox to have ability to run "Docker quickstart terminal" under windows 8

Actual result: azure commands, like `az acr`, are normally running under cmd/powershell, but not running just in docker quickstart terminal:

```
$ az
bash: az: command not found
```

Expected result: I want to have ability to run "az" commands family just in docker toolbox ("Docker Quickstart Terminal") on windows 8.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - using alias, e.g.

```
alias az='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe" -Im azure.cli'
```

If You have better variants - please add. I will close question as answered in few days

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the azure cli 2.0 is installed in location, and this path isn't added to the PATH variable.

So you should add the PATH to windows **Environment Variables** -> **Path**.

Here is my path:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jason. In description I mentioned, that PATH is added.